# Diamonds aren't highlighted when a moderator reviews a suggested edit on their own post

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, design, moderators

Just noticed this on [this suggested edit](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9301):

[image]

The diamond being outside the blue owner-highlighting looks really weird. Pretty sure it used to be inside the highlighting. Could it be moved back?

Comment: Yep, thanks for finding that @Shadow.