# Add back the highlight on the author's name on suggested edit reviews to their own posts, or indicate the author otherwise

Tags: feature-request, design, review, suggested-edits, original-poster

In the old UI for the review queues, it used to be that if the author reviewed a suggested edit to their own post, their name would be highlighted:

[image: Highlighted author name]

([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246235/diamonds-arent-highlighted-when-a-moderator-reviews-a-suggested-edit-on-their-o))

However, this is no longer the case:

[image: Name no longer highlighted]

This leads to [confusing situations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388235/bad-edit-approval?noredirect=1) where it appears that a single non-mod user was able to override other users making the opposite review, i.e., it's unclear why their vote was binding or why they were allowed to override a previous review outcome. The prior highlight made this clear, but now this isn't clear anymore.

I posted this as [a feedback answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361916/377214) at the time the new review queue design was rolling out, but it didn't get a response, and a staff member [told me to post it again as a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues/361916#comment1294472_360198).

Like I said on the feedback answer, I understand that the prior blue highlight (which matched the background for the author on user cards on questions as well as on comments they made) isn't feasible here as it's the same color as the background, so it will just mix in and not be visible, but please re-add in an indication (e.g., in text) that the author reviewed a suggested edit, as there used to be before.

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but it may be possible to do this with a userscript