# Add an owner indicator to the suggested edit review after it has been reviewed

Tags: bug, design, review, suggested-edits, owner

When a review has been evaluated by the question asker (OP) in the suggested edit review, it fails to indicate that it was reviewed by the question asker. Typically, the question asker's identity is highlighted in the comment section, and it should similarly be displayed in the reviewer section.

Upon inspecting the elements, it was discovered that the "owner" CSS class was added in the comments section but is missing in the reviewer section. Furthermore, both the background color of the "owner" CSS class and the reviewer section are identical, indicating that simply adding the CSS class will not resolve the issue; it requires additional design adjustments.

Sample [suggested edit review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/88347) and Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Owner indicator is missing]

Comment: I already requested this: [Add back the highlight on the author's name on suggested edit reviews to their own posts, or indicate the author otherwise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388257/add-back-the-highlight-on-the-authors-name-on-suggested-edit-reviews-to-their-o) This used to be present in the old design of the queue, but for some reason was removed from the newer design. I initially posted it as an answer to the announcement of the new queue design, but it got passed over, and staff told me to post it as a new question.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I couldn't find your question in my search. Nonetheless, I've closed my question as a duplicate of yours.